# Undefined reference to (SFML)

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors, sfml

I am trying to link SFML with CMake, but I have some issues with make:

```
/home/ishidex2/Documents/QtCreator/CMakeExample/main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'
```

And some kind of errors like this.

First of all, I installed SFML by this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev
```

And then followed this tutorial :

https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Build-your-SFML-project-with-CMake

I think this is a problem with linking, but I don't know how to fix it.

My linking order is:

```
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED graphics window main system)
```

Comment: Did you make any changes to the makefile provided in the tutorial? Can you please include your makefile in the body of the question?

Comment: No, just copied it.

Comment: Even if you have copied the code from the site "as is", Stack Overflow **requires** to add the code to the question post itself. Simple link is NOT sufficient. For the case you use SFML 2.5, the tutorial has a note at the head: `!!! This tutorial doesn't work for SFML 2.5 anymore !!!`. (If you use older SFML without shipped CMake config file, I wonder how did you make the `find_package(SFML)` to work: the link to the file `FindSFML.cmake`, which you should download and add to your project, is **dead**.)

Answer (score 2):

`find_package` does not perform any linking, you need to use `target_link_libraries` as seen in the link that you posted yourself:

```
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
```

Comment: I copied the CMakeLists.txt file from the tutorial but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that I do, when coding sfml in Linux, or Debin Raspberry Pi 4 in my case, is to install code blocks.  It comes with a project setup for quite a few toolkits, including SFML.  You just start a new project and choose 1.6 or 2.0 and then click ok and it puts a skeleton in the code editor already equipped with a window and texture loaded immediately, to get you off on the right foot.  Hope that helps.